# ajaxForm is not working ie 10

Tags: jquery, form-submit

Am using ajax form plugin. this is the link http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api for the plugin..

```
jQuery('#update-personal-information-form').ajaxForm( {

                            beforeSubmit: function() {
                jQuery('#update-personal-information-form').validate({

                errorClass: "error",
                    errorElement: "div",
                rules:{
                    first_name:{required:true},
                    last_name:{required:true},                  
                    email:{required: true, email:true},
                    dob:{required: true,dateISO: true}

                },
                messages:{
                    first_name:{required:" First Name:cannot be blank"},
                    last_name:{required:" Last Name:cannot be blank"},
                    email:{required:" Email:cannot be blank"},
                    dob:{required:" Date Of Birth:cannot be blank",dateISO: "Invalid date. Must be formatted yyyy-mm-dd"}

                }
                });
                return jQuery('#update-personal-information-form').valid();
            },


            success: function() {

                    var url1 = './index.php?r=user/personal_information';

                    jQuery("#dialog_edit_personalinfo").remove();

                    jQuery("#body1").load(url1);


            } 
    });
```

this is working in all the browsers fine, but in i.e 10 it is working as form submit and page is refreshing. I am searching from the last four hours, but no results found, please help me in this. thank you..

Comment: are you using the latest release of jquery-form plugin

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. The POST call is going through without any form data.